# Read APIGatewayProxyRequest from gin.context

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, lambda

I am using github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-go-api-proxy/gin to create a API.
I want to read APIGatewayProxyRequest out of gin.Context if possible or please suggest other better way?
Here is my request handler,

```
func handleRequest(ctx context.Context, req *events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    db := persistence.InitializeDB()
    defer db.Close()

    router := router.NewApiRouter()

    if ginLambda == nil {
        ginLambda = gin.New(router.Initialize()) // here I send req to router, which I want to use in endpoint handler
    }

    response, err := ginLambda.ProxyWithContext(ctx, *req)

   ...

    return response, err
}
```

Here is my handler for post request,

```
func (ser *Service) GetUserRecordByID(context *gin.Context) {
// here I want to read APIGatewayProxyRequest object. I can log context, but not sure how to read APIGatewayProxyRequest object? 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution, using aws lambda proxy core..

```
import (
"github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-go-api-proxy/core"
)

func (ser *Service) GetUserRecordByID(context *gin.Context) {
apiGWRequestContext, ok := core.GetAPIGatewayContextFromContext(c.Request.Context())
}
```